# Running Firebase web SDK under phantomjs fails to authenticate valid tokens (auth/network-request-failed)

Tags: firebase, phantomjs, firebase-authentication

I am trying to use `phantomJS` to create a pdf of a authenticated part of a Firebase web app.

The set up is as follows

1. A cloudFunction is triggered when firestore is updated.
2. The cloudFunction creates a custom token with `admin.auth().createCustomToken` with the relevant claims.
3. A url to the hosted firebaseapp app is created, with the token as a query param.
4. The URL is given to `phantomjs` to create a pdf of the page.
5. When the firebase webapp boots, it grabs the token, and uses `firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken`
6. On success it renders the page.

The hosted page works fine, and I can grab the token that the cloudFunction creates, add it to the URL and test it all in chrome with no issue.

However, when running this under phantomJS, the call to `admin.auth().createCustomToken` fails with

`auth/network-request-failed` .
`A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred.`

I have tried the following

1. Setting `'--ignore-ssl-errors=yes', '--ssl-protocol=tlsv1', '--web-security=false'` on PhantomJS
2. Setting `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` `*` on the `hosting` `firebase.json` rules
3. Setting a `Content-Security-Policy` for all the google apis on the `hosting` `firebase.json` rules

Does anyone know what would be blocking the google api within `phantom`?

Could it be the `User agent`?

Comment: Can you get the `cURL` command to simulate a request coming from PhantomJS? I don't think it is user agent related. Or can you grab the actual network error that is being thrown in the underlying network request? Is the request actually going out? You could also try calling the request yourself from PhantomJS using the REST API: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/#section-verify-custom-token This could shed some light on the failure reason.

Comment: @bojeil Thanks for the response, ill try your REST idea tomorrow and let you know if I can grab the actual issue....

Comment: @bojeil Strange, the REST api works fine!!  The response was . 
 `{"kind":"identitytoolkit#VerifyCustomTokenResponse","idToken":"[REDACTED]","expiresIn":"3600","isNewUser":false}`

Comment: Are you calling the REST API via phantomJS? It would be helpful if you can pinpoint the reason why the client SDK fails in phantomJS so Firebase Auth can fix this issue.

Comment: Yes - both are being called from within a phantom JS page.  The REST call via `$.ajax` comes back with a successful response, but the `firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken` fails.    Ill see if i can log more on the error from the SDK

Comment: Thanks, fixing this for everyone else would be great. Thanks.

Comment: This was using a prototype app, ive now opened another question with the same issue but running under an AngularFire2 app.   I have narrowed down the issue a bit. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48096280/firebase-signinwithcustomtoken-fails-under-phantomjs-when-hosted-on-firebase  if I get an answer Ill update both

Comment: @bojeil Done a lot more testing today - managed to use the REST api to get the idToken, and the set that into localstorage for the SDK to use.  This is all working fine locally, but again has the same error once on Firebase.  So it looks like its ANY SDK call on firebase under phantom that dies.   Could this be some whitelist / blacklisting of domains ???  it works fine using a firebase hosted web page, but a locally hosted cloud function.  Its only when phantom runs off the FB servers does it fail.

Comment: Are you saying, it will work on other non firebase hosted domains in phantomjs?

Comment: @bojeil, yes!  It works when locally hosting the cloud function ( `firebase serve --only functions`).  Hitting the local http cloud function, which captures a *remote* hosted firebase web app works.  It's only when the cloud function is *Firebase* hosted does it fail.   Im going to create a git hub repo with demo code....

Comment: @bojeil Ok, i've put together a demo app.  So, it is ONLY the auth that fails, other calls to get public data from firestore work.   Here is a hosted example  https://hello-firebase-ea30c.firebaseapp.com/ . and the repo to checkout and run locally / see the code.  https://github.com/mattbryson/phantomjs-firebase-auth-issue

Comment: I've added a ticket to the SDK git repo as this has become a blocker for us now.  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/419